# Loops and Class Going Wrong

Tags: class

The following code has an Syntax error meassage on the 2 lines starred. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
    import pandas as pd # data processing, CSV file I/O
    import os
    import warnings
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import tqdm
    from keras.preprocessing.image import  load_img
    warnings.filterwarnings ('ignore')

    input_path = []
    label = []

   **for class in os.listdir("dog-vs-cat-classification"):
      **for path in os.listdir("dog-vs-cat-classification/"+class):
            if class == 'Cat':
                label.append(0)
            else:
                label.append(1)    

            input_path.append(os.path.joim("PerImages", class_name, path))`
```

Comment: What's the error message?